# Glue for sticking wool to wool?

Tags: adhesive, materials

Can anyone recommend glue for sticking wool to wool? This is for a small, stationary, non-load-bearing, long-term application for an indoor, non-heated environment.

I would be willing to pay more for something that checks various "hippy" boxes, such as being extra-safe for humans, or less environmentally destructive or economically exploitative to produce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aerosol contact adhesive,  it ticks none of your extra boxes, but works well on deformable things. like wool batts.